# #1066 - Not unique table/alias:

Tags: mysql, sql

Can you please help me out. I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT l.url 
FROM (b INNER JOIN links ON b.parent_id = l.id) 
INNER JOIN b ON l.id = b.link 
WHERE l.url LIKE 'http://domain%' LIMIT 0, 30
```

And somehow it says

```
#1066 - Not unique table/alias: b
```

Comment: Is that the actual script?  I don't see where you're defining `l` as an alias.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You seem to be selecting from the same table twice. Each of these occurrences needs its own alias:

```
SELECT
    l.url
FROM
    b as b1 /* <-- */
    INNER JOIN links as l
      ON b1.parent_id = l.id
    INNER JOIN b as b2 /* <-- */
      ON l.id = b2.link
WHERE l.url LIKE 'http://domain%' LIMIT 0, 30
```

Please note that I also added the missing alias `l` for the `links` table.

Comment: `You seem to be selecting from the same table twice` helped me today `:)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT l.url from b inner join links as l on l.id = l.parent_id
inner join b as b1 on b1.link = l.id
where l.url like 'http:domain%' limit 0,30
```

In this query we r join two table first b and second links and self join b as b1 alias ok