# Error Number: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'service' in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, inner-join

Want to get all services in one to many relationship
My code is

```
$this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('service');
    $this->db->join('user', 'user.user_email = service.user_email', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('service', 'service.user_email = user.user_email', 'inner');
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

But it gives me an error

```
Error Number: 1066

Not unique table/alias: 'service'

SELECT * FROM (`service`) INNER JOIN `user` ON `user`.`user_email` = `service`.`user_email` INNER JOIN `service` ON `service`.`user_email` = `user`.`user_email`

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\service\system\database\DB_driver.php
```

If I do without

```
$this->db->from('service');
```

Then it gives syntax error

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN `user` ON `user`.`user_email` = `service`.`user_email` INNER JOIN `se' at line 2

SELECT * INNER JOIN `user` ON `user`.`user_email` = `service`.`user_email` INNER JOIN `service` ON `service`.`user_email` = `user`.`user_email`

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\service\system\database\DB_driver.php
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are selecting from `service`, and then joining `service` again (after joining `user`)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590007/1066-not-unique-table-alias follow this . you will get your answer. you are selecting sample table twice.

Comment: But it gives an syntax error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to join the `service` table to the `user` table and then trying to join the `service` table again.

This isn't something you should generally be trying to do, and when you do it this way, the rendered SQL statement contains two attempts to reference the `service` table. It's the second `JOIN` that causes the database pain and it throws the error that you're seeing.

In this instance, just use:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('service');
$this->db->join('user', 'user.user_email = service.user_email', 'inner');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Since the

```
$this->db->join('service', 'service.user_email = user.user_email', 'inner');
```

is redundant here (you've already joined these tables on that field.